# Converting web to Sitecollection guidelines

Tags: site-collection, migration, web

What are the points should be considered before converting web to Sitecollection in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Some points to consider moving your site (SPWeb) to site collection (SPSite):

1. Shared permissions (usually span across multiple sites and lists)
2. Galleries for templates
3. Content types (Content types are provisioned at site collection level)
4. Web Parts
5. Shared branding
6. Common navigation scheme
7. Site collection quotas (to control storage limits) with management at content database level

Comment: do we have any step by step article somewhere?

Comment: There is general guidance over the topic available at MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263267.aspx